# Kubernetes service-cluster-ip-range do not work for pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flannel, kubectl

I setup k8s use docker-multinode with [some fix](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-deploy/issues/215), the cluster ip range changed to `--service-cluster-ip-range=172.16.0.1/24`, but I got both 10 and 172 ip for pod.So the container with 10 IP can not access by other server.

[image]

I only expected 172 ip for pod, why assign 10 ip for pod ?

Comment: Could you provide more details of your configuration? The flag `--service-cluster-ip-range` configures the services IP ranges, and not the pods IPs. If you are using Flannel you also need to make sure the IP range is correctly set in etcd.

Comment: the `--service-cluster-ip-range` specifies a range of IPs that shouldn't be routable inside your cluster. These are for virtual IP that will be associated with your `services` not pods. They will provide access to the pods matching a service labels via iptables rules configured on your kubernetes nodes by the kube-proxy.

Comment: @FélixCantournet There is an `--pod-cidr` param for [kubelet](http://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/), after I set this, the network become wired,but the ip addree is ok.

Comment: I'm having something similar today but flannel value is correct.  Did you ever this this solved? @wener

Comment: No,but I don't play k8s recently, maybe this is solved in 1.5